# How can I make unique user "sessions" for my Django web application running on heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I made a web application using Django, that stores information in python arrays that are accessed by the user via the front-end. My problem now is that since I have deployed it via heroku, you can't use the website on more than one device, or else options selected from one device affects the website data for all devices.

How would I be able to make it so that user experiences are different / unrelated? How can I alter the views.py (or other components) so that the web application has a "session" for each user?

This is for a django web application running on heroku. The application is for my school, and it's akin to a battle-royal type site. Users can select people displayed on the site, which in turn removes them from a python dictionary that's stored in memory and puts them in another dictionary for later. The problem is, if more than one person is using the site at one time, they access the same dictionary. I haven't a clue what to try to solve this.

"processor.py"

```
names, accepted = list(), list()
# names contains many names of people, accepted is empty

def accept_person(person):
    if person in names:
        accepted.append(person)
        names.remove(person)

    else:
        a = difflib.get_close_matches(person, names)
        if len(a) > 1:
            accepted.append(a[0])
            names.remove(a[0])
        else:
            pass
```

"views.py"

```
def view_home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if(request.POST.get("yes")):
            processor.accept_person(request.POST.get("yes", False))
```

Accepting a person on one device accepts that person for everyone accessing the site. I want to be able to have one "session" per user, so that one person changing this python dictionary doesn't affect everyone's experience.

Comment: Django has built-in session support.  Why can't you use that?

Comment: Is session support with Django for this specific purpose?

Comment: The purpose is to store a separate session for each user, yes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for here is a way to authenticate users, Django is brilliant for this and handles basically all of it for you.

But if you really want a full solution with minimal effort I would take a look at a package called django-allauth.

The official docs (https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) can be a bit daunting so here is a good tutorial I followed the first time I integrated authentication into Django.

https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial/